# What would standing on top of Barad-dur, or relatively close to the Eye of Sauron, feel like?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, sauron

Besides probably being hot, would there be any adverse effects if one were to stand on top of Barad-dur, close to the Eye of Sauron?

Comment: If you're referring to the giant floating eyeball of doom, that was basically made up for the movies so there's not really any source to draw from. In the books, "the eye" was a metaphor or at best a vision, and not a physical phenomenon.

Comment: See http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14489/how-big-is-the-eye-of-sauron and http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27657/was-the-eye-of-sauron-saurons-actual-physical-form about whether the eye even existed.

Comment: ...although the concept of the "Eye" in this question is fine if the OP clarifies that a movie-canon answer is sought, it's still not an answer that can be provided based on the available materials.

Answer (score 7):

At around 1,400 meters high, you would have slightly less oxygen. Breathing could be a little bit more labored. Also at that height the wind could be quite strong.

Comment: But what about the enormous flaming eye next to you?

Comment: @Richard That might cause your breathing to be even more labored.

Comment: @MattGutting - Would it burn up the available oxygen, I mean.

Comment: @Richard depends on where the flames were coming from. Maybe they piped the fire from somewhere else.

Comment: @MattGutting - His gas bill must have been monstrous

Comment: it could have been a flame burning other types of gas not oxygen, Or a fun fancy magical flame that didn't actually burn anything at all.

Comment: I bet he never paid his gas bills though. He was that evil.